# I am not able to redirect registered user to dashboard page with link

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, amazon-cognito

```
if (response.success) {
            this.redirectURL = response.data.loginUrl;
            // this.URL='http://'+location.host+'/login'+'/'+this.redirectURL;
            this.router.navigate(['/login?token=', this.redirectURL]);}
```

Here is the code ,it should move me to cognito page but its moving to login page in angular I am not sure where I am wrong

Comment: What URL do you want it to go to?

Comment: response.data.loginUrl this url I want to concatenate with /login while navigating

Comment: pleae help someone

Answer (score 0):

use **+(plus)** instead of **,(comma)**

```
 this.router.navigate(['/login?token='+this.redirectURL]);}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use query params, you can also adopt this approach.

```js
this.router.navigate(['login'], { queryParams: { token: 20 } });
```

Most likely the reason behind the issue you are facing is that the comma-separated navigation turns to slash-separated one, e.g.

```js
let redirectURL = '1234'
this.router.navigate(['/login?token=', redirectURL]) 
// this line above results to  /login?token=/1234'
```

So in order to avoid that you should either use the solution that I suggest or the one mentioned by abhishek sahu, where the usage of `+` for concatenation is encouraged.